# C# Event driven state machine needs to release event raiser using Windows.Forms.Timer

Tags: c#, timer, state-machine, event-driven

In our legacy VB6 code we used a system timer to perform a callback so that state machines could be run without blocking event handlers. Some Psuedo code example

```
Sub Unhooked(State info)
    Select Case info
        Case 1
            NextState = somestate1
        Case 2
            NextState = somestate2
        Case 3
            NextState = somestate3
    End Select
    RunStateMachine
End Sub

Sub RunStateMachine()
    MyObject.GoDoSomethingAndCallMeBack
End Sub

Sub MyObject_EventCallback(State info)
    APITimer.SetUpCallBackTarget (Unhooked, info)
    APITimer.CallMeBackInASec
End Sub
```

Hopefully you get the idea where some call is made in the state machine that will result later on in the event handler being fired and it sets up a timer to do a callback so that the event handler code can complete before we move on to the next state.

I am continuing a similar vein in C# but it feels wrong as I'm sure the language would provide a cuter way of doing this. Since my C# state machine is still calling VB6 objects that raise events on the UI thread, is there a better way of 'unhooking' the event handler so that it is released before the state machine continues on it's way?

I thought I could use BeginInvoke to add a message to the pump to run the state machine but on the same thread instead of a thread pool thread but my class isn't a form or control. I think I could come up with a solution that doesn't use timers but, well they are dead simple to use for this so any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you could queue a `Task` to the UI thread context, e.g.:

```
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Unhooked(info), CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None, ui);
```

The UI `SynchronizationContext` can be detected even though your object is not a form or control. For more information on `SynchronizationContext`, see [my MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx).

If you have this in your code a lot, you'll probably want to wrap it up into a helper method:

```
public void CallbackLater(Action action)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

void MyObject_EventCallback(State info)
{
  CallbackLater(() => Unhooked(info));
}
```

In the broader scheme of things, seriously consider the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) and designing a [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern API](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204847) instead of having the events raised on the UI thread (i.e., the Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern).